# DataGrid column size width fit to cell content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have this XAML code:

```
<Window>
    <Grid Name="gridBase" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Name="dgPatchContent" Margin="10, 20, 10, 10" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SoftwareName}" Header="Software Name" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding AssignmentStatus_Stopped, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Stopped" MinWidth="55" CanUserResize="False" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding AssignmentStatus_New, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="New"  MinWidth="55" CanUserResize="False" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding AssignmentStatus_Pilot, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Pilot"  MinWidth="55" CanUserResize="False" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding AssignmentStatus_Productive, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Prod"  MinWidth="55" CanUserResize="False" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="OK" MinWidth="80" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" MinWidth="80" Margin="0,10,10,10" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The DataGrid is filled with objects containing some dummy values for testing purposes. The first few entries in the SoftwareName column have rather short strings (~10 characters). At the bottom I've added a large string (~60 characters).

I want to have the Cells have the Width of the largest string in that column when the application launches. Currently when I start it, the Width is the size of the largest string which is visible in my `DataGrid`. Only when I scroll to the bottom the `DataGrid` and Window resizes to the Width of the large 60char string.

I've played around with `Width="SizeToContent"` or "`SizeToCells`" but nothing seems to make the `DataGrid` have the correct size after the application has launched. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `DataGrid` has [row virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enabled by default, so only visible row objects are created initially, and the grid itself knows only about currently visible cells sizes:

> When the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to true, the DataGrid
>   does not instantiate a DataGridRow object for each data item in the
>   bound data source. Instead, the DataGrid creates DataGridRow objects
>   only when they are needed...

If your `DataGrid` is not a big one, then a most simple solution will be just to set `EnableRowVirtualization="False"`, then the sizing will work from the start.

Comment: That fixed the problem instantly! Thanks so much for the explanation. I didn't know about RowVirtualization.

Comment: @sev, glad it helped, have fun coding =)